# Аутентификация API по токену. Не удается получить SSOSessionId. Использую Python requests

Tags: python, api, requests, аутентификация

Пытаюсь получить доступ к API для дальнейшей работы. Не могу пройти аутентификацию по токену. Согласно документации:
"3.1.1 Аутентификация.
Для получения доступа к API сначала требуется провести процедуру аутентификации пользователя системы "Интернет-Банк "Биз-нес" в Системе Единой Аутентификации Банка (SSO) и получить SID - идентификатор сессии SSO (SSOSessionId). При работе с API при-ложение должно поддерживать протоколы безопасности SSL.
Аутентификация проходит на странице Банка, которая вызывается по ссылке, содержащей адрес возврата:
-auth_url(ссылка в документации )
SID будет содержаться в cookie ответа в поле auth_sid при успешной аутентификации. Пример SID: 0034696077-bae38d.
Так как аутентификация проходит на странице Банка, ее требуется вызывать из ПО которое будет использовать API. "

Делаю запрос:

```
import requests

token = "токен"
auth_url = "ссылка_для_аутентификации"

headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"
}

response = requests.get(auth_url, headers=headers)
print(response.cookies)
```

В response.cookies нужного(auth_sid) поля не нахожу. Да и если пытаюсь сделать запрос неправильным токеном, все равно куки не меняются. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: А почему вы решили, что ваш код написан "Согласно документации"?